# Failed because incorrect arithabort setting

Tags: sql, unique-index, non-clustered-index, filtered-index, arithabort

I created a unique index (case description should be unique if IsDelete != 1)

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UniqueCaseDescription]
ON [tblCases] ([fldCaseDescription] ASC) 
WHERE [IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS varbinary(1))
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then when I run the following procedure it throws 'UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with filtered indexes.'

```
ALTER PROC [usp_DeleteCase] (@fldCaseID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN   
    UPDATE tblCases
    SET IsDeleted = 1
    WHERE fldCaseID = @fldCaseID

    RETURN 1
END
```

I tried adding SET ARITHABORT ON before the UPDATE statement, but that didn't do anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What DB compatibility level are you using? Try setting it to a higher version (ideally, the actual version of your DB engine :)).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SQL Server` try to apply the following settings:

1) Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2) Right click the database name you use and select Properties>Options menu. Then set Arithmetic abort enabled = True from the opened dialog.

**Note:** I also tried to apply the same settings by using script, but using this method via SSMS is better to apply this setting.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Turned out I didn't need to use a filtered index, so I didn't get a chance to try your solution. Thank you for your help anyways! Maybe it'll help somebody else having the same problem.